# Sending blob or byte array in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, jakarta-ee, xmlhttprequest

I am a novice back end developer. I am developing a REST webservice. My requirement is to send BLOB content from the server to Mobile Side. My douubt is, is it possible to send BLOB in XML or should I convert it into ByteArray and send it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all. 
Convert your Bitmap into ByteArray and then Convert that byte array to Base64 String format and send that Base64 String format in xml.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , baos); //bmp is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now send `encodedImage` in your xml...

Base64 to bitmap conversion

```
public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(String Base64String) 
{
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(Base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply BB Expert, I will try it.

Comment: BB Expert, can you help me with the reverse engineering?

Comment: yo! that worked, but the application is really slow, I am running netwrok connection, SAXParsing and DB insertion  in a background thread..

Comment: You need to compress the image and then try to upload it. then it will work average fast.

Comment: sure, thanks for your reply, the abover requirement is for logo. On an average each logo is coming upto 20000 characters[]. Is this too huge?